# StringBuilder.AppendFormat fails with few params

Tags: .net, vbscript

```
Set sb = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
Call sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", 1, 2)
```

Fails with:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment:  sb.AppendFormat

`sb.AppendFormat("{0}", 1)` works fine.

Comment: @HansPassant: could you tell more detaily about the format statement, please? I'm bit confused about string formatting in VBS. Is there analog of AppendFormat?

Comment: VBScript can use only COM, not .Net, meaning it can use .Net classes and objects only if they expose a COM interface. I suspect that the COM interface of the `StringBuilder` class makes only a limited subset of all its method available. Have you considered using PowerShell instead of VBScript?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Unfortunately it's legacy code, there is no way to rewrite it with PowerShell. Anyway, thank you for the info!